# Open source level editor for HTML5 platform game?

Tags: javascript, html5, level-design, map-editor

A natty GUI editor is very helpful to create level map. I want to use some open-source choices rather than build my own from scratch. I found [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) but it doesn't work for what I want.

Though I'm building HTML5 game, I don't have to use a HTML5 level editor as long as it can output well-formatted map files which my javascript can read.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the confusion. Tiled does not work for me because to make the player perform a 'tricky' jump, sometimes I want to set the distance between two platforms to, say, 7/3 or 8/3 tiles. But in Tiled I get only 2 or 3. If Tiled can do this, please teach me.

Comment: Why is Tiled not suited for your platformer? Please be more specific about your requirements... do you need to freely position differently sized sprites?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: Just for information. You can set properties for every tile in Tiled. So if you want to add special information, like the platform distance, you can simply add a property stating the distance... As far as I know, you can define these properties on the map par tile position and also in the sprite sheet selector, where the property will be used for every drawn tile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tiled is very well suited for a platformer. But it really depends on how you design your tiles. Usually you'll have small tiles that are repeatable and form your landscape. Special corner- and edge-tiles can be used for a better look. Here's an [example of such a sprite-sheet](http://read.pudn.com/downloads3/sourcecode/games/6257/isometric/Chapter10/IsoHex10_3/IsoHex10_3__.jpg).

If you'd like to position sprites freely (eg. you're not working with tiles), I can recommend an editor like [GLEED2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D). The editor writes to XML files, but these can easily be changed to something else by using XSLT or some other way of processing the XML data.

Comment: Just a quick point on Gleed2D -- the codeplex project has been abandoned, a new fork that is (slightly more actively) maintained is on github: https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D

Answer (score 2):

I use Tiled too.

It seems strange that you're trying to do. You can create an Object Layer in TIled and set a position for your platform, but it is mostly used for movable objects. If your platform will be fixed it's weird not having an exact size in tiles.
Maybe you're using the wrong technology to make your scenarios. Maybe using Bitmask will help you.
See this [tutorial](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/), it has several ways to implement a platform map.

Anyway, some alternatives to TIled are [TileStudio](http://tilestudio.sourceforge.net/) and [Dame](http://dambots.com/dame-editor/). But Dame are made for use with Flixel(as3), maybe it will be difficult to integrate with HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

More relevant for HTML5 would be ImpactJS which is a framework but a level editor included. Granted the cost is $99 but you get a working platformer game, the level editor, support & the framework.

http://impactjs.com/

Definately worth a look and could be a great starting point for a game.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking at something free for now, try the MightyEditor
http://mightyfingers.com/editor-features/
Cheers!